# CakePHP Controller error

Tags: cakephp

Hi I am an absolute beginner for cakephp. I have created a controller tasks_controller.php and the class name is TasksController according to cake naming conventions as tasks is my table name in the database.I have put index action in this controller but i run this in browser, I get this error,

Missing Controller

Error: TasksController could not be found.

Error: Create the class TasksController below in file: app\Controller\TasksController.php

}

My url is : localhost/cakephp/tasks/index

I am quite new so don't know how to fix this problem. I am using cakephp 2.4.0.

Please help me in this.

Comment: tasksController or TasksController? respect the casing.

Comment: TasksController is my controller name and file name is tasks_controller.php. Is something wrong in my naming conventions ??

Comment: can you please explain whats wrong with my code. Thanks

Comment: Where did you find that it should be "tasks_controller.php"? Please post the link. The documentation sure does not.

Comment: I followed this tutorial just for understanding of cakephp. I did what they have said in this tutorials, Please visit this link to confirm where is the actual mistake .


http://www.packtpub.com/article/create-a-quick-application-in-cakephp-1?registered=true

Comment: This is supposed to be your bible: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples.html - especially as beginner!

Comment: yes, it was the fault using old naming convention, thanks you helped me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create the class TasksController below in file: app\Controller\TasksController.php

You have called your file tasks_controller.php. Read the error carefully ;-)

The naming convention for controller files was updated in cakephp 2.0. Looks like you are using the old 1.x conventions

Comment: Sometimes I wonder how an error message could possibility be any more descriptive as it already is.. :)

Comment: @mark, Please have a look this link.

http://www.packtpub.com/article/create-a-quick-application-in-cakephp-1?registered=true

Comment: @cowls your are right, it was due to the old naming conventions, i have used. now i changed it and it works well now. Thanks i accepted your answer.